# Source file when changing pwd

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to develop a functionality in bash that will source file the *first* time I am changing pwd to target dir (and its' subdirectories) in a newly opened terminal session.
I was thinking about setting an alias that will be a commands sequence of:

```
cd [...] && src [...]
```

but that would source the file each time I am changing pwd which is not needed.
I was hoping if there is data storing info about currently sourced files by bash  - then I could make a simple case struct in `.bashrc`.

Any suggestions how can I resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since I am fresh user I cannot type new tags - I would strongly reccomend the admin to add 'source' as a tag.

Comment: The `source` tag was killed off a while ago: [Have this tag return to the \[source\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302467/608639)

Comment: tags are primarily to help long-time readers focus their search to topics they are interested in helping with. I filter by the tags [bash], [awk], and [linux]  among many others. I don't think anyone is searching for source and if you goto the tags page, you will see it is not listed (it could be, but not really helpful in the Stackoverflow context) All in IMHO. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can just export variable via `export SOURCE_SET=1` and each time just check if is present in environment and then avoid doing `source`.

Comment: Note that if you make any changes to the file you are sourcing, you'll have to source the file manually or `unset SOURCE_SET` to get the new changes.